# PLSQL select query in BEGIN block

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validate_date
AS

strABC DATE;
strDummy VARCHAR2(20);

CURSOR C_Example IS SELECT * from dummytable;

BEGIN    

    FOR R_Example IN C_RetNxWeek LOOP
      strABC := R_RetNxWeek.something;
      strDummy := R_RetNxWeek.something;

    END LOOP;


      IF (something < something) THEN 

      ELSE
         strDummy:= SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE something = something;  <-----alternative to do this?

      END IF;       
 END validate_date;
```

I have a very basic store procedure template like above, i have a cursor that will select some record from a table, in the IF ELSE statement in BEGIN block, i wish to do a checking on a data by selecting a table, since i cannot put cursor in BEGIN block, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The select statement result cannot be stored as you stated,
it should be done via

It should use `INTO` Clause please refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

No need of an explicit cursor, use a `CURSOR FOR LOOP`. I don't know your requirement, since I think it could be done using plain `SQL`. However, if you really want to use `PL/SQL`, you can make use of `BULK COLLECT` and `FORALL`.

And regarding the `SELECT`, you need to use `INTO` clause in `PL/SQL`.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    eno       NUMBER;
  3    STR_DUMMY VARCHAR2(20);
  4  BEGIN
  5    FOR i IN
  6    (SELECT * FROM emp
  7    )
  8    LOOP
  9      eno := i.empno;
 10      dbms_output.put_line(eno);
 11    END LOOP;
 12    SELECT ENAME INTO STR_DUMMY FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO = 7788;
 13    dbms_output.put_line(STR_DUMMY);
 14  END;
 15  /
7369
7499
7521
7566
7654
7698
7782
7788
7839
7844
7876
7900
7902
7934
SCOTT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```